# How to get the cell selection row in our own declaration method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, segue

I have button in `UITableView` if user select the button then it have to go NextViewController [with carry of some JSON values].

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    orderid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrDictionary objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"orderid"]];
    NSLog(@"orderid==%@",orderid);
}
```

I can easily get the values from the selected cell

I have button in `UITableViewCell` so i need to get the button click is from which row?

I tried with this code but its only display first `orderid` i have stored

```
-(void)nextview:(UIButton *)button
{
    NSIndexPath *index=[tableview indexPathsForSelectedRows];
    orderid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrDictionary objectAtIndex:index]objectForKey:@"orderid"]];
    NSLog(@"orderid==%@",orderid);
}
```

Comment: `[tableview indexPathsForSelectedRows]` should return a `NSArray`, not a `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: oh ok  ,i will change that @Larme

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If you have not working with multiple selection then you can get one row which is selected by :**

```
NSIndexPath *index = [tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
```

**If you have multi row selection then :**

You will get the array of selected `NSIndexPath` of selected index as like :

```
NSArray *selectedIndexPaths = [tableview indexPathsForSelectedRows];
```

You can run loop up to the `selectedIndexPaths.count` and get selected rows data.

---

DOCUMENT :

```
// Selection

- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForSelectedRow;
// returns nil or index path representing section and row of selection.
- (NSArray *)indexPathsForSelectedRows NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0); 
// returns nil or a set of index paths representing the sections and rows of the selection.
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get selected cell as

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]];
```

and indexPath as `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]`

and I think you'll then pefror a segue

```
    [self perfromSegueWithIdentifier:@"Segue"];
```

Answer (score 0):

For Push json to NextViewController

```
-(void)YouButtonSelector:(UIButton *)sender{
NextViewController *rightController=[[NextViewController alloc] init];
rightController.eventIdIs=self.event_id;
rightController.PreviousJson=PresentJson;
rightController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed=YES;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:rightController animated:YES];

}
```

For Button Clicked

```
 [cell.checkboxBtn setTag:indexPath.row];
 [cell.checkboxBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(nextview:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

  -(void)nextview:(UIButton *)button
  {
  NSLog(@"Button select is :%d",button.tag);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can give button tag in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method

```
button.tag = indexPath.row;
```

2 - you have receive you orderid

```
-(void)nextview:(UIButton *)button
{

NSString *orderid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrDictionary objectAtIndex:button.tag] objectForKey:@"orderid"]];

NSLog(@"orderid==%@",orderid);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign

```
cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row;
```

and on button press function get data from array using

```
UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
NSString *str = arrDictionary[btn.tag];
```